# Deploy jBPM 7.8.0 in Tomcat - Not able to Login using tomcat user

Tags: java, tomcat7, jbpm, kie-workbench, kie-server

I am trying to deploy jBPM 7.8.0 in tomcat.

I have placed the war files in webapps directory in tomcat 7.0.40. Java 1.8.

I have made the changes as per the readMe files in kie-server & kie-wb war files.

I am able to deploy the wars. Login page is coming up. But I am not able to login. Error is `Login Failed: Not Authorized`

Logs attached.

Tomct users:

```
<role rolename="admin"/>

<role rolename="PM"/>

<role rolename="HR"/>

<role rolename="analyst"/>

<role rolename="user"/>

<role rolename="kie-server"/>



<user username="testuser" password="testpwd" roles="admin,analyst,PM,HR,kie-server"/>

<user username="kieserver" password="kieserver1!" roles="kie-server"/>
```

Note - Read me file does not mention configuring the bitronix trxn manager.

Can anyone help me with this?

In catalina.bat, catalina options is set to:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS= %CATALINA_OPTS% -Djbpm.tsr.jndi.lookup=java:comp/env/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.ds=java:comp/env/jdbc/jbpm -Djbpm.tm.jndi.lookup=java:comp/env/TransactionManager -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.tm=JBossTS -Dhibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction -Dorg.kie.server.id=tomcat-kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:7001/kie-server-7.8.0/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:7001/kie-wb-7.8.0/rest/controller -Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\Aravind\Installation\Tomcat_8\webapps\kie-wb-7.8.0\WEB-INF\classes\login.config -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk
```

LOG:

```
    -----
    WARNING: Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:7001/kie-wb-7.8.0/rest/controller/server/tomcat-kieserver error Read timed out
    Jul 17, 2018 10:11:11 PM org.kie.server.services.impl.ControllerBasedStartupStrategy startup
    WARNING: Unable to connect to any controllers, delaying container installation until connection can be established
    Jul 17, 2018 10:11:11 PM org.kie.server.services.Bootstrap contextInitialized
    INFO: KieServer (id tomcat-kieserver) started successfully
    Jul 17, 2018 10:11:11 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
    FINE: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[/kie-server-7.8.0]] to [INITIALIZING]
    .......

    Jul 17, 2018 10:12:12 PM org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl connect
    INFO: Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:7001/kie-wb-7.8.0/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
    Jul 17, 2018 10:12:12 PM org.kie.server.common.KeyStoreHelperUtil loadControllerPassword
    WARNING: Unable to load key store. Using password from configuration
    Jul 17, 2018 10:12:17 PM org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl connectToSingleController
    WARNING: Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:7001/kie-wb-7.8.0/rest/controller/server/tomcat-kieserver error Read timed out
    Jul 17, 2018 10:12:24 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator validateCustomBean

    .....
    FINE: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener@52feb982] to [STARTED]
    Jul 17, 2018 10:13:34 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
    FINE: Setting state for [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]] to [STARTED]
    Jul 17, 2018 10:13:34 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
    FINE: Setting state for [StandardService[Catalina]] to [STARTED]
    Jul 17, 2018 10:13:34 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
    FINE: Setting state for [StandardServer[8005]] to [STARTED]
    Jul 17, 2018 10:13:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 186332 ms
    ....

    Jul 17, 2018 10:15:30 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
    FINE: Security checking request POST /kie-wb-7.8.0/j_security_check
    Jul 17, 2018 10:15:30 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator authenticate
    FINE: Authenticating username 'testuser'
    Jul 17, 2018 10:15:30 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
    FINE:  Failed authenticate() test ??/kie-wb-7.8.0/j_security_check
    Jul 17, 2018 10:15:33 PM org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl connect
    INFO: Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:7001/kie-wb-7.8.0/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
    Jul 17, 2018 10:15:33 PM org.kie.server.common.KeyStoreHelperUtil loadControllerPassword
    WARNING: Unable to load key store. Using password from configuration
    Jul 17, 2018 10:15:33 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
    FINE: Security checking request PUT /kie-wb-7.8.0/rest/controller/server/tomcat-kieserver
    ------------
```

Comment: Tomcat user DB setup was missing. This issue is fixed. 
But I cannot see the process definitions 
roles given in tomcat-users.xml.
Also given the role in web.xml in workbench war and kie server war (kie-server, rest-all, rest-client ).
Now shown in the roles page in the workbench. 
when I click on the process definition/instance, there is an error:
     "Process Definitions could not be loaded. Check if the jBPM Capabilities are enabled and if the remote server is correctly set up."
Many roles added in Tomcat show in workbench as groups.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: refer the url for more details on this ISSUE:
https://developer.jboss.org/message/984244#984244 Can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the latest log from the link which you provided. I can see that the jBPM extension has been successfully registered:
"jBPM KIE Server extension has been successfully registered as server extension"

So the process capabilities should be available. The only possible explanation is that the server template(tomcat-kieserver) has been registered in the time when you had issues with database which disabled jBPM extension in Kie server.

Can you please try to delete current server template in Kie Workbench and restart Tomcat to let Kie server register back to the Kie Workbench? If all Kie server extensions are correctly initialized it should enable all capabilities in Kie Workbench.